# Google App Engine Memcache Object Types

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

Very short questions : Can I only store objects of type Entity in GAE's memcache or does it support other types ?

Thanks

Comment: You could test this for yourself in about 30 seconds...

Answer (score 5):

For Java you can use every object that implements java.Serializable as stated in the Javadoc https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheService

Answer (score 2):

For Python: according to the [source](http://code.google.com/searchframe#Qx8E-7HUBTk/trunk/python/google/appengine/api/memcache/__init__.py), any type is acceptable.

```
def add(self, key, value, time=0, min_compress_len=0, namespace=None):
"""Sets a key's value, iff item is not already in memcache.

  Args:
    key: Key to set.  See docs on Client for details.
    value: Value to set.  Any type.  If complex, will be pickled.
    ...
```